# Improving MySQL search performance with 100 million rows

Tags: mysql

I went through all the other questions of SO. My case is almost the same as most of the questions.

I have 100 million of records in my database `mysql-innodb`; I'm using php8 with CodeIgniter 4, I have a fear that if my rows reach 100 millions records will my simple search queries will work faster

`select * from table where firstname='Sufian' and lastname='Shaikh'`

I wanted to know the best possible way to search faster; I already indexed the columns that I'll use for searches; but there are 30 columns out of which 7 columns are indexed and will be used maximum time for searching through the database.

Do I discard MySQL and go for other databases like PostgreSQL, MongoDB, and Elasticsearch, my project will not run online it will be running on a local system within the office premises not outside for the public.

Here is my screenshot of the indexes. What can I do to improve them?

[image]

[image]

[image]

My queries will be a search form that includes all the fields from the table, there will be no joins, just pull records from one single table and show and export options.

There will be `where` `orWhere` `like` `orLike` etc; these queries will be performed, but my question is whether it can able to handle 10 million of rows and show results as fast as fast possible.

So basically I want a way to select from 10 million of records and perform search on them too.

Comment: You don't have to discard MySQL - it is pretty normal to set up a search-specific system like Elasticsearch as a mirror.

Comment: Include `SHOW CREATE TABLE` so we know what indexes you actually have. Consider full text indexes if applicable. In this case you *must* have an index on both of those columns, not individually, but combined.

Comment: @tadman, thanks will provide more info in a few minutes... thanks for your important time... as I have to hide the columns names and make them random so my privacy is maintained

Comment: Totally understand. It's just hard to give specific advice without a little more detail here.

Comment: give me some days; I'll edit the questions and provide more details, as of now I have fewer details to show and add; hence it would be great if I could test more with 100 million records and test the no.of seconds it takes to give results etc with and without indexed tables with same data.

Thanks for everyonee

Comment: but I hope mysql can handle 100 millions records?

Comment: yes, it can.  your sample query does not need a full text index, but would benefit from a composite index.  when asking optimization questions, please include (as text not images) your full actual query, output of `show create table yourtablename` for all tables used in your query (which will show your columns and indexes in a maximally useful form), and output of `explain ...rest of your query`

Comment: Your example query is doing a full table scan, as there is no usable index. Add a composite index on `(firstname, lastname)`. You may find these useful - [Multiple-Column Indexes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/multiple-column-indexes.html) and [Optimizing Queries with EXPLAIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/using-explain.html).

Comment: I voted to reopen; @user1191247 has the answer.  I'll add:  Don't use `FULLTEXT` for single-word columns; use an ordinary `INDEX` if needed.